# Nginx - Redirect only main domain and not subdomain to WWW

Tags: nginx

How can I setup a redirection in Nginx conf to only redirect the main domain and not subdomain to WWW using `$host` or `$server_name`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    server_name your_domain_without_www;  
    location / {
         rewrite   ^(.*)$ http://your_domain_with_www$1 permanent;
    }
}

server {
     server_name *.your_domain_without_www;
     ...
}
```

You could also split the second *server* section into 2 separate ones if you need to handle www.your_domain and other subdomains of your domain differently.

Comment: subdomains still being redirected

Answer (score -2):

Use .htacess file to redirect the url this will solve your problem

Comment: I know this can be achieved via htaccess, but what I want is something like `if ($host !* www\.(.*)$) {
    return 301 $scheme://www/$1$request_uri;
}` under the server block of Nginx conf. Do you have any idea of how?